# About Bayesian Analysis Exponential Poisson distribution

Tags: r, statistics, bayesian, mcmc

I am a student who is currently learning about Bayesian analysis of exponential poisson distribution.
I can't find the code that produces the output of the figure described in the paper "Bayesian analyses of an exponential Poisson and related zero augmented type models". Can someone please just give me some advice?
Thank you in advance.
To add about the image, I could only get so far on my own.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO!  You will be most likely to get your question answered if you follow the [helpful advice](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) about asking questions and create a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).  In this case, it sounds like you want help coding the model.  To do that, we would need some data and an understanding of how you want to parameterize the model.

Comment: that code looks like a strange mixture of R and Stan code.  also [please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)